# Is cache sharding a part of out-of-the box functionality of neo4j-HA?

Tags: neo4j

... or users should somehow tune (or turn on or whatever else it might be) this feature?

Suppose I have a graph of approximate size of 100GB. How much RAM  should I have on each node in order to gain a significant performance growth?

Answer (score 2):

For a graph of ~100GB I'd recommend 128 GB of RAM:

- assign the size of your graph to MMIO cache layer, approx 100GB, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_file_buffer_cache
- assign as much of remaining RAM to JVM heap (-Xmx). With increasing heap, full garbage collection stw pauses increase - typically with a heapsize of 16-20 GB its still acceptable.

The heart of cache sharding is to route request touch the same region of your graph to the same cluster member. For a lot of use cases a trivial session sticky routing is good enough. See documentation of your load balancer for details - the LB is not part of Neo4j.